# Keep going mode for require-package

Tags: package, error-handling

In my initialization file, I have got:

```
(require-package 'clips-mode)
```

The thing is that, lately, this package fails to be loaded sometimes (it's already downloaded but I guess it fails when it tries to check for new versions of the package), and when this happens, the initialization file stops reading and subsequent sentences are not read.

I'd like to know if there are a way to ignore errors and keep going even if this specific `require-package` sentence fails, so the rest of the initialization code is applied anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You can wrap that in `ignore-errors`, to ignore any error evaluating it might raise:

   ```
   (ignore-errors (require-package 'clips-mode))
   ```
2. If you want to ignore only particular errors then you can instead wrap it with `condition-case`:

   > `condition-case` is a special form in `C source code`.
   >
   > `(condition-case VAR BODYFORM &rest HANDLERS)`
   >
   > Regain control when an error is signaled.
   >
   > Executes `BODYFORM` and returns its value if no error happens.
   >   Each element of `HANDLERS` looks like `(CONDITION-NAME BODY...)`
   >   where the `BODY` is made of Lisp expressions.
   >
   > A handler is applicable to an error
   >   if `CONDITION-NAME` is one of the error’s condition names.
   >   If an error happens, the first applicable handler is run.
   >
   > The car of a handler may be a list of condition names instead of a
   >   single condition name; then it handles all of them.  If the special
   >   condition name `debug` is present in this list, it allows another
   >   condition in the list to run the debugger if `debug-on-error` and the
   >   other usual mechanisms says it should (otherwise, `condition-case`
   >   suppresses the debugger).
   >
   > When a handler handles an error, control returns to the ‘condition-case’
   >   and it executes the handler’s `BODY...`
   >   with `VAR` bound to `(ERROR-SYMBOL . SIGNAL-DATA)` from the error.
   >   (If `VAR` is `nil`, the handler can’t access that information.)
   >   Then the value of the last `BODY` form is returned from the `condition-case`
   >   expression.
   >
   > See also the function `signal` for more info.
3. Why not try to find out what error is raised and why?  Set `debug-on-error` to `t` before that `require-package` gets invoked (without using any `ignore-errors` or `condition-case`), and look at the resulting debugger backtrace.  It might be better to take care of the cause of such an error, rather than just ignoring it.